# Calculating a power in Java without power function in O(log) time

Tags: java, algorithm

I had this question sent to me by a potential employer, and my answer apparently wasn't up to snuff.  Can anyone help?

> Implement a function that calculates power(A,B), where A and B are
>   positive integers, assuming there is no power function in your
>   programming language. Also, assume A and B are of Big Integer type so
>   that there is no arithmetic overflow. What is the computational
>   complexity of your function? Can you come up with a solution that runs
>   with log(B) time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just give you a hint.  Suppose B is 45.  Then A<sup>45</sup> = A<sup>32</sup> * A<sup>8</sup> * A<sup>4</sup> * A<sup>1</sup>.  You can compute A<sup>1</sup>, A<sup>2</sup>, A<sup>4</sup>, A<sup>8</sup>, etc. by starting with A and squaring it in every iteration.